# binary_search to find a class object by the return variable of its member function [c++]

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, binary-search

I have a vector of class objects sorted by its integer indices. But the index of an object is generated by the member function of the class - so no `int id` is stored as a member variable.

```
class boundary
{
     public:
     int get_id();
}

std::vector<boundary> sample;
```

Now I need to find the `boundary` object ,which's `int id` generated by `get_id()` is same as the `int value` I'm searching.

```
auto &iter = binary_search(sample.begin(),sample.end(), 5, custom_function)
 //should compare iter.get_id() == 5
```

Is it possible to use binary_search in this case? How do I achieve this?

Comment: If the id is generated by the `get_id` function and does not store it in a field then I am pretty sure that you will either get the same `id` returned for all objects when they call the function or get a large number of possible id's for an object in either cases a binary search will be unpractical.

Comment: Just remember that the sample (the vector) might not contain the object you are looking for. What do you want your function to return in that case?

Comment: @Andrzej, the object which I'm searching should be there in the vector. I've to assert it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use std::lower_bound in this case:

```
bool custom_function(boundary& obj, int id)  { return obj.get_id() < id; }
...
auto iter = lower_bound(sample.begin(),sample.end(), 5, custom_function);
```

(replace function pointer with function object if you want better performance)

Answer (score 2):

Assumption: you want to obtain a *reference* to the sought element (rather than an iterator to it).

```
boundary& find_boundary(std::vector<boundary>& sample, int id)
// precondition: a boundary with id does exist in the sample
{ 
  auto less_by_id = [](boundary const& b, int id) // lambda is faster than function pointers
    { return b.get_id() < id; };

  auto it = lower_bound(sample.begin(), sample.end(), id, less_by_id);

  assert (it != sample.end());
  assert (it->get_id() == id);
  return *it;      
}
```

Now, you can use it:

```
boundary& b = find_boundary(sample, 5);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create an object which satisfies the "Compare" concept.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare

For example:

```
class Compare {
public:
    bool operator()(boundry a, boundry b) {
        return a.get_id() < b.get_id();
    }
}
```

Comment: Although true this does not answer the question.